# Finding time complexity of partition by quick sort metod

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Here is an algorithm for finding kth smallest number in n element array using partition algorithm of Quicksort.

```
    small(a,i,j,k)
     {
      if(i==j) return(a[i]);
      else
      {
      m=partition(a,i,j);
      if(m==k) return(a[m]);
      else
        {
         if(m>k) small(a,i,m-1,k);
         else small(a,m+1,j,k);
        }     
       }
     }
```

Where i,j are starting and ending indices of array(j-i=n(no of elements in array)) and k is kth smallest no to be found.
I want to know what is the best case,and average case of above algorithm and how in brief. I know we should not calculate termination condition in best case and also partition algorithm takes O(n). I do not want asymptotic notation but exact mathematical result if possible.

Comment: the best case is easy if(i==j) on the first iteration it will return the answer, so the best case is 1.  Might I suggest you rewrite your code, so that the parameters a,i,j,k have names that represent what they actually are!  It's difficult to read code with not very well labeled variable names.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: no if(i==j) is termination condition and it is only for n=1 not for large values of n.

Comment: "Best case complexity" is an utterly useless metric.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm assuming the array is sorted - something you didn't mention - because that code wouldn't otherwise work. And, well, this looks to me like a regular binary search.

Anyway...

The best case scenario is when either the array is one element long (you return immediately because i == j), or, for large values of n, if the middle position, m, is the same as k; in that case, no recursive calls are made and it returns immediately as well. That makes it O(1) in best case.

For the general case, consider that T(n) denotes the time taken to solve a problem of size n using your algorithm. We know that:

T(1) = c

T(n) = T(n/2) + c

Where c is a constant time operation (for example, the time to compare if i is the same as j, etc.). The general idea is that to solve a problem of size n, we consume some constant time c (to decide if m == k, if m > k, to calculate m, etc.), and then we consume the time taken to solve a problem of half the size.

Expanding the recurrence can help you derive a general formula, although it is pretty intuitive that this is O(log(n)):

T(n) = T(n/2) + c = T(n/4) + c + c = T(n/8) + c + c + c = ... = T(1) + c*log(n) = c*(log(n) + 1)

That should be the exact mathematical result. The algorithm runs in O(log(n)) time. An average case analysis is harder because you need to know the conditions in which the algorithm will be used. What is the typical size of the array? The typical size of k? What is the mos likely position for k in the array? If it's in the middle, for example, the average case may be O(1). It really depends on how you use this.

Comment: ok you mean best case is O(1).Also it is not binary search its partition algorithm.So the relation should be T(n)=T(n/2)+n

Comment: I thought m=partition(a,i,j) is just the same as m=(i+j)/2 .. ?